# Case when then in postgresql doesn't work as expected (on null value)

Tags: postgresql, null, case

I have this table called people

| id | name | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith |
| 2 | Robert | Williams |
| 3 | Peter | Walker |

if I run the query

```
select CASE WHEN id is null THEN '0' ELSE id END as id
from people 
where id='2'
```

The result is:
| id
| ----
| 2

I want to display **id** as **0** when it is Null in the table, but when I run

```
select CASE WHEN id is null THEN '0' ELSE id END as id
from people 
where id='4'
```

| id |
| --- |
|  |

My expected result is:
| id
| ----
| 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A top-level SQL query that doesn't match any rows will return zero rows, which is different from returning NULL. This makes sense, because it lets you distinguish between the result for `SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=4` when there is no such user and the result when there is a user but their email is null.

However, a subquery that returns no rows will evaluate to NULL the way you expected. So you can rewrite your code like this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT id FROM people WHERE id = '4'), 0 );
```

`COALESCE(x,y)` is shorthand for `CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN y ELSE x END`. It's helpful in cases like this where the expression for x is long and you don't want to have to write it twice.